# How do I route traffic from HTTPS PORT 5400 to HTTP 5402 in IIS 7.5?

Tags: ssl, iis, https, url-rewriting, arr

We currently have external HL7 messages being sent to https using port 5400 with SSL certificates on IIS7.5. The messages are meant to be sent to http port 5402 interface. I've tried the Redirect option in IIS. The Client reports the certs are working but they get a 301/302 response. The interface shows no connection attempt was made.
The interface engine has NO option to handle SSL certs so I have to use IIS.
I've heard you can do this with [ARR and URL Rewrite] but have no clue how incorporate the different ports or if even this can be done.

Summary of traffic routing:
https://localhost:5400 -> http://localhost:5402

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with ARR + URL rewrrite. Create a rule like this

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for you help. I did get this work. I had to bind the https on port 5400 with the SSL cert. Add a similar rule - Wildcard - Pattern = *; Ignore case[checked]; Condition-Blank; Server Var -Blank; Action= Rewrite; Rewrite URL=http://192.xxx.xxx.xxx:5402; Append query[checked]; Log written[unchecked]; Stop process[Unchecked]